# $E(|X_1+X_2|^p)<+\infty$ iff $E(|X_1|^p)<+\infty,E(|X_2|^p)<+\infty$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables. Show that for any $p>0$,
$$E(|X_1+X_2|^p)<+\infty \text{ iff } E(|X_1|^p)<+\infty,E(|X_2|^p)<+\infty$$
Show that this is false if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.

I tried to use the Hölder's inequality but it got nowhere. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

My attemp:

We remember that
$$ E (X) = \int_{\Omega} X d P $$
$(\Leftarrow)$
If $p \geqslant 1$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \| X_1 + X_2 \|_p & \leqslant & \| X_1 \|_p + \| X_2 \|_p\\
    \left( \int_{\Omega} | X_1 + X_2 |^p d P \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} & \leqslant
    & \left( \int_{\Omega} | X_1 |^p d P \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left(
    \int_{\Omega} | X_2 |^p d P \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    E (| X_1 + X_2 |^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} & \leqslant & E (| X_1
    |^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} + E (| X_2 |^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
    E (| X_1 + X_2 |^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} & < & + \infty\\
    E (| X_1 + X_2 |^p) & < & + \infty .
  \end{eqnarray*}

If $0 < p < 1,$
\begin{eqnarray*}
    (a + b)^p & \leqslant & a^p + b^p, \forall a, b \geqslant 0\\
    | X_1 +  X_2 |^p \leqslant (| X_1 | + | X_2 |)^p &
    \leqslant & | X_1 |^p + | X_2 |^p\\
    | X_1 + X_2 |^p & \leqslant & | X_1 |^p + | X_2
    |^p\\
    \int_{\Omega} | X_1 + X_2 |^p d P & \leqslant &
    \int_{\Omega} | X_1 |^p + | X_2 |^p d P\\
    \int_{\Omega} | X_1 + X_2 |^p d P & \leqslant &
    \int_{\Omega} | X_1 |^p d P + \int_{\Omega} | X_2 |^p d P\\
    E (| X_1 + X_2 |^p) & \leqslant & E (| X_1 |^p) + E
    (| X_2 |^p)\\
    E (| X_1 + X_2 |^p) & < & + \infty .
  \end{eqnarray*}
$(\Rightarrow)$ For the implication, I think I should use variable independence $X_1$,$X_2$, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: what about Minkowski's inequaliy?

Comment: For $p \geq 1$ use Minkwoski's inequality. For $0<p<1$ use the fact that $(a+b)^{p} \leq a^{p}+b^{p}$ for all $a, b \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for their suggestions, I could already prove the converse, but for I can't prove the implication yet. I show my progress above.

Answer (score 1):

For the implication $\Rightarrow$: using Fubini's theorem and independence, we have
$$
\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_1+X_2\rvert^p \right]=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_1+y\rvert^p\right]d\mathbb P_{X_2}(y),
$$
where $\mathbb P_{X_2}$ is the law of $X_2$; this implies that $\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_1+y\rvert^p\right]$ is finite for at least one $y$ and we get that $\lvert X_1\rvert^p$ has a finite expectation.

This implication fails if we do not have independence: let $X_2=-X_1$, where $X_1$ is such that $\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_1\rvert^p\right]$ is infinite.